# Crystal Report multiple static & dynamic columns using multiple timeframes

Tags: crystal-reports

I have a report with multiple static columns relating to a customer, where I want to also list 3 separate items for different time periods for comparison in additional columns.  I am not sure if I should try to do it with formulas for those time periods.  I have tried to figure out crosstab reports, which seems straight forward on the surface, but cannot seem to accomplish what I want either.  Suggestions would be appreciated.

Static Information Report columns are:
Group  Branch  Agent #  ContactName  CompanyName (followed by the repeating columns for time periods   #FILES   INVOICETOTL   PAYMENTS  BAL)  These repeating columns would be monthly figures based on the invoice date which is not appearing in a column

EXAMPLE
GRP1  RP 1234  John James  Simplifle Co  5  $3000  $2000 $1000   7 $300 $200 $100 The 5 $3000 $2000 $1000 is the info for January
the 7 $300 $200 $100 is the info for February
Hope this is making some sense

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. SO is not a coding service. You have to put atleast some effort to solve your own problem, before others are willing to help. Please check out how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: hard to understand what is your problem.. can you show raw data and also how you would like to view the same in reports

Comment: Use Suppress if duplicate